# System.ListException: List index out of bounds

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I encountered this error while deploying my code
[image]

Looking at the issue, it seems everything is pointed at one particular class. I am currently unsure of where it is going wrong or what causes the issue. Attached the code below

ProductRequiredTrigger:

```
trigger ProductRequiredTrigger on ProductRequired (before update, before Insert, after Insert, after update, after delete) {

//Retrieving Custom Metadata to activate/deactivate trigger
List<LTNG_TriggerControl__mdt> triggerControl = [Select DeveloperName, MasterLabel, LTNG_AfterDelete__c,LTNG_AfterInsert__c,
                                                 LTNG_AfterUndelete__c,LTNG_AfterUpdate__c,LTNG_BeforeDelete__c,
                                                 LTNG_BeforeInsert__c,LTNG_BeforeUpdate__c from LTNG_TriggerControl__mdt 
                                                 where DeveloperName='ProductRequiredTrigger' LIMIT 1];

// Trigger on before Insert
if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert && triggerControl[0].LTNG_BeforeInsert__c == true){ 
    ProductRequiredTriggerHandler.onBeforeInsert(Trigger.New);
}

// Trigger on before update
if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate && triggerControl[0].LTNG_BeforeUpdate__c == true){ 
    ProductRequiredTriggerHandler.onBeforeUpdate(Trigger.New, Trigger.oldMap);
}    


// Trigger on After Insert
if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert && triggerControl[0].LTNG_AfterInsert__c == true){ 
    ProductRequiredTriggerHandler.onAfterInsert(Trigger.New);
}

// Trigger on After Update
if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate && triggerControl[0].LTNG_AfterUpdate__c == true){ 
    ProductRequiredTriggerHandler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.New, Trigger.oldMap);
}

// Trigger on After Update
if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isDelete && triggerControl[0].LTNG_AfterDelete__c == true){ 
    ProductRequiredTriggerHandler.onAfterDelete(Trigger.Old);
} }
```

ProductRequiredTriggerHandler:

```
public without sharing class ProductRequiredTriggerHandler {
public static void onBeforeInsert(List <ProductRequired> productRequiredList) {
    
    Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (ProductRequired prodReq: productRequiredList) {
        productIds.add(prodReq.Product2Id);
    }
    
    if(! productIds.isEmpty())
        calculateTotalPrice(productIds, productRequiredList);
}

public static void onBeforeUpdate(List<ProductRequired> newProductRequiredList, Map<Id, ProductRequired> oldProductRequiredMap) {
    
    Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (ProductRequired prodReq: newProductRequiredList) {
        if(prodReq.Product2Id != oldProductRequiredMap.get(prodReq.Id).Product2Id)
            productIds.add(prodReq.Product2Id);
    }
    
    if(! productIds.isEmpty())
        calculateTotalPrice(productIds, newProductRequiredList);
}

public static void calculateTotalPrice(Set<Id> productIds, List<ProductRequired> productRequiredList) {
    
    List<PricebookEntry> pricebookEntries = new List<PricebookEntry>();
    pricebookEntries = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Product2Id IN :productIds];
    
    Map<Id, PricebookEntry> pricebookEntryMap = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>();
    for(PricebookEntry pbe : pricebookEntries){
        pricebookEntryMap.put(pbe.Product2Id, pbe);
    }
    
    for(ProductRequired prodReq : productRequiredList){
        if(pricebookEntryMap.containsKey(prodReq.Product2Id)){
            prodReq.LTNG_UnitPrice__c = pricebookEntryMap.get(prodReq.Product2Id).UnitPrice;
        }
    }       
}

public static void onAfterInsert(List<ProductRequired> productRequiredList) {
    Set<Id> saIds = new Set<Id>();        
    for (ProductRequired prodReq: productRequiredList) {
        saIds.add(prodReq.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c);            
    }
    
    if(!saIds.isEmpty())
        calculateNetPayableAmount(saIds);
}

/**
 * @description : method for all After Update Actions
 * @param productRequiredList : list of new productRequired records
 **/
public static void onAfterUpdate(List<ProductRequired> productRequiredList, Map<Id, ProductRequired> oldProductRequiredMap) {
    
    Set<Id> saIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (ProductRequired preq : productRequiredList){
        if(preq.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c != oldProductRequiredMap.get(preq.Id).LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c || preq.LTNG_TotalPrice__c != oldProductRequiredMap.get(preq.Id).LTNG_TotalPrice__c)  
            saIds.add(preq.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c);
    }    
    
    if(!saIds.isEmpty())
        calculateNetPayableAmount(saIds);
}

public static void onAfterDelete(List<ProductRequired> oldProductRequiredList) {
    
    Set<Id> saIds = new Set<Id>();        
    for (ProductRequired prodReq: oldProductRequiredList) {
        saIds.add(prodReq.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c);            
    }
    
    if(!saIds.isEmpty())
        calculateNetPayableAmount(saIds);
}

public static void calculateNetPayableAmount(Set<Id> saIds) {
    
    Map<Id, List<ProductRequired>> prodReqMap = new Map<Id, List<ProductRequired>>();
    for (ProductRequired prodReq: [SELECT Id, LTNG_TotalPrice__c, LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c FROM ProductRequired WHERE LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c IN :saIds AND isDeleted = FALSE]) {
        if(!prodReqMap.containsKey(prodReq.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c)){
            prodReqMap.put(prodReq.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c, new List<ProductRequired>());
        }
        prodReqMap.get(prodReq.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c).add(prodReq);
        System.debug('prodReqMap::' +prodReqMap +'prodReqMap::' +prodReq);
    }
    
    List<ServiceAppointment> serviceAppointmentList = [SELECT Id, Net_Payable_Amount__c FROM ServiceAppointment WHERE Id IN :saIds];
    for(ServiceAppointment sa : serviceAppointmentList){
        sa.Net_Payable_Amount__c = 0.00;     
        if(prodReqMap.containsKey(sa.Id)){
            for(ProductRequired prodReq : prodReqMap.get(sa.Id)){
                sa.Net_Payable_Amount__c = sa.Net_Payable_Amount__c + prodReq.LTNG_TotalPrice__c;
            }   
        }
    }
    
    if(! serviceAppointmentList.isEmpty()){
        update serviceAppointmentList;
    }
} }
```

productRequiredTestTrigger:

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public class ProductRequiredTriggerTest {

static testMethod void productRequiredTestTrigger() {
    
   WorkType workTypeRecord = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createWorkType(true);
    FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c policy = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createSchedulingPolicy(true);
    OperatingHours operatingHourRecord = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createOperatingHours(true);
    ServiceTerritory territoryRecord = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createServiceTerritory(true, 'Launceston', 'Footscray', '7250', 'Australia', operatingHourRecord.Id);
    WorkOrder testWorkOrderRecord = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createWorkOrders(1, true, workTypeRecord.Id, territoryRecord.Id)[1];
    
    DateTime earliestStartTime = DateTime.now();
    DateTime dueDateTime = earliestStartTime.addDays(7);
    
    ServiceAppointment newSA = new ServiceAppointment();
    newSA.ParentRecordId = testWorkOrderRecord.id;
    newSA.Status = 'None';
    newSA.EarliestStartTime = earliestStartTime;
    newSA.DueDate = dueDateTime;
    newSA.Net_Payable_Amount__c = 1020;
    
    insert newSA;
    
    Product2 product = new Product2();
    product.Name = 'Product X';
    product.Duration__c = 30;    
    product.ProductCode = 'productX';
    product.LTNG_ProductType__c = 'Equipment';
    insert product;
    
    Product2 product1 = new Product2();
    product1.Name = 'Product Y';
    product1.Duration__c = 30;    
    product1.ProductCode = 'productY';
    product1.LTNG_ProductType__c = 'Equipment';
    insert product1;
    
    ProductRequired newProductRequired = new ProductRequired();
    newProductRequired.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c = newSA.id;
    newProductRequired.Product2Id = product.id;
    newProductRequired.QuantityRequired = 1;
    newProductRequired.ParentRecordId = testWorkOrderRecord.id;
    insert newProductRequired;
    
    Pricebook2 customPricebook = new Pricebook2(
        Name = 'Price Book',
        IsActive = true
    );
    insert customPricebook;
    
    PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
        Product2Id = product.Id,
        UnitPrice = 1020,
        IsActive = true
    );
    Insert pbe1;
    
    PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id,
        Product2Id = product.Id,
        UnitPrice = 1020,
        IsActive = true
    );
    Insert pbe;
    
    newProductRequired.Product2Id = product1.Id;
    update newProductRequired;
    
    newProductRequired.QuantityRequired = 2;
    update newProductRequired;     
    
    delete newProductRequired;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the trigger isn't part of the deployment, and the old trigger logic is still being run. In that code, you query a CMDT, then select the first item out of that list `[0]`. If this CMDT doesn't exist in the target environment, this would cause this `ListException` to occur. As far as I can tell, this is the only possible explanation, as there are no other `List` being used by index anywhere in the code you've presented.

Make sure that the trigger is included as part of the deployment.

Comment: Thanks for this I missed that one, but it still displayed the same errors however, I believe I have resolved the issue, will be posting the Answer if it works. Thanks